# How to remove the menu title from homepage in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I tried to look online for this but everything I found, gives instructions on how to remove the article title... and I don't want to remove the article title.
The website is http://dev.iguardsystem.it/
The article title is: Rilevazione Presenze - Controllo Accessi - iGuard which is fine, that I want to keep.
On top of that, it's shown the title of the home menu-item, which, in this case, is: Home.
How can I hide that?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently the "Page heading" option, removes the Home menu-item title.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the text shown in the red border in the image below:

[image]

Then this is the Breadcrumbs module. You can disable it by going to :

**Joomla backend** >> **Module Manager** >> **Find the Breadcrumbs module** >> **Unpublish**

Comment: No, I'm not referring to the breadcrumbs. I'm referring to the big h1 that says Home in the homepage...

Answer (score 0):

Click on the menu item > Under the "Menu Title" are a number of tabs. Click on the "Page Display" tab > Change "Browser Page Title" to the name you want.
Does this help?